# How to use global list in decision table Drools ? Global variables in Decision tables

Tags: jboss, global-variables, drools, spreadsheet, kie

I'm new bee to drools. I need to use global array list in drools decision table(SpreadSheet).  I tried adding it in the variables section. But I am getting a null pointer exception while accessing the array list.

Is it good to use global variables in decision tables ?
Please advise on this.

Reference - https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.32.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#_wb.artifactrepository

Comment: Global variables are almost never a good idea. Why can't you just pass the list into working memory?

Comment: Thanks@roddy. Can you pls share me some examples if possible?

Comment: Of what, passing the list into working memory? Just pass it the same way you pass all the other data into the rules.

Comment: @Debugger i have provided the solution kindly try and let me know if this works

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use Global variables the declare the variables row in RuleSet Declaration table.

[image: Example RuleSet Declaration with Decision table]

***How to add the Global Variable values ?***

> drools.getKnowledgeRuntime().setGlobal("abc", new Class1());
>   drools.getKnowledgeRuntime().setGlobal("xyz", new Class2());

Hope this helps !!!